# Bind9 DNS:Configure A Local Forwarding DNS Server

Tags: dns, bind

i've a small local network Containing(for example):

1. A Ubuntu 14.04 PC As a DNS Server[192.168.1.10]
2. chat.Server1 on 192.168.1.11
3. chat.Server2 on 192.168.1.12
4. chat.Server3 on 192.168.1.13

And I want a local name resolution From Bind on these devices i see many instructions that is unrelated to my willing and i think i get lost and need a step by step from the start instruction.

Comment: I don't exactly get the point. Are you talking about port forwards (or Natting), or about a Name Resolution to be setup?

Comment: @s1mmel
Simply for not understanding(you not understand it probably) give me a -1?!
it a Local DNS between 4 devices in a network that one of them is a DNS and others registered on it!

Comment: 1. Your question was confusing because of the words you used and this is not to blame you or make fun of you. I'm here to help people like you. 

but more important

2. this is a question which does NOT show any research effort. Looks like you don't know how to google or you too lazy

But hey I'm a decent guy so

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-bind-as-a-private-network-dns-server-on-ubuntu-14-04

Have fun with it.

I removed the -1 even if you would deserve it.

Comment: I would suggest the [Ubuntu Serverguide](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/dns.html). It is the only reference I used to do exactly what you are wanting to do.

Comment: @s1mmel
tnx for the instruction,before i ask this question i'd follow exactly that one.